# Como activar y desactivar seguridad biometrica en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-biometrico

Estoy integrando la seguridad biométrica de una aplicación para que el usuario active y desactive la función cuando lo crea necesario , pero hasta ahora con lo que he investigado no que dado con el caso, este es el codigo que tengo escrito y funciona , pero necesito saber como hacer que el usuario active y desactive la seguridad biometrica.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Biometrics
private Executor executor;
private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);

    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,
            executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                          @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);

            if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
                // user clicked negative button
                finish();
            } else {

                //TODO: Called when an unrecoverable error has been encountered and the operation is complete.
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Authentication error: " + errString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });



    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Seguridad Biometrica para tu aplicacion.")
            .setSubtitle("(se recomienda este metodo para mayor discreción)")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancelar")
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
            .build();


    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);

   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos a ver si te puedo ayudar

Es un tema muy complicado de explicar, pues lo tengo adaptado a mi trabajo y no va a coincidir con el tuyo, de todas formas, a ver si te sirve

Verás:

Yo tengo un gif animado en la pantalla de identificación, que un pricipio está oculto.

En la base de datos tengo un campo booleano.

En la página de registro, tengo un icono de huella, si accede, le pregunta si autoriza el acceso por huella dactilar y guarda true (1) en la base de datos

Aquí te muestro los métodos de la página de resgistro donde almaceno el valor 1 para true o el valor 0 para false en función de si acepta o no la identificación, y guarda el número de socio de ese usuario en el archivo de preferencias creado

```
private void metodoAutorizarDatosBiometricos()
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pstP = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().prepareStatement("UPDATE Usuarios SET " +
                "Biometric = " + 1 + " WHERE Socio = " + socio);
        pstP.executeUpdate();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Autorizado el Uso de tus Datos Biométricos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pstP.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private void metodoDenegarDatosBiometricos()
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pstN = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().prepareStatement("UPDATE Usuarios SET " +
                "Biometric = " + 0 + " WHERE Socio = " + socio);
        pstN.executeUpdate();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Denegado el Uso de tus Datos Biométricos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pstN.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private void metodoGuardarPreferencias()
{
    SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("Credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencias.edit();
    editor.putString("Soc", socio);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Al cargar la página de indentificación, pregunta al archivo de preferencias si hay número de socio almacenado, si lo hay, es que el usuario ya está registrado

```
//icono oculto si no está autorizada la identificación por huella
img_huella.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

//aquí accedo al método de preferencias que almacena el número de socio
String soc = metodoCargarPreferencias();

private String metodoCargarPreferencias()
{
    SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("Credenciales", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String soc = preferencias.getString("Soc", "null");
    return soc;
}
```

Si hay número de socio, lo envío al método abrir huella y me devuelve true o false

Este método pregunta a la base de datos si la lectura de la huella está autorizada, si lo está, almacena true en la variable y muestra el logotipo de la huella, luego llama al método de autentificación de huella dactilar

```
if (soc != null) {
        //abrimos el método AbrirHuella
        boolean acceso = metodoAbrirHuella(soc);
        if (acceso == true)
        {
            img_huella.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(R.raw.huellas)
                    .into(img_huella);
        }
    }
```

el método abrir huella

```
public boolean metodoAbrirHuella(String soc)
{
    boolean acceso = false;
    try
    {
        Statement stH = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().createStatement();
        ResultSet rsH = stH.executeQuery("select Biometric from Usuarios where Socio = " + soc);
        while (rsH.next())
        {
            if (rsH.getInt("Biometric") == 1){
                metodoAutentificacionHuellaDactilar(soc);
                acceso = true;
            }
        }
        rsH.close();
        stH.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return acceso;
}
```

El método autentificación huella es el encargado de validar al usuario

```
private void metodoAutentificacionHuellaDactilar(String soc)
{
    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(this, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);

            Toast.makeText(PaginaLogin.this,"Identificación exitosa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            metodoAccesoUsuario(soc);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            Toast.makeText(PaginaLogin.this,"No se reconoce al usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();

            Toast.makeText(PaginaLogin.this,"Error en la identificación",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Touch id required")
            .setDescription("Touch the touch id sensor")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Exit")
            .build();

    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
}
```

Si la identificación resulta positiva, llama al método de acceso que es el que le dirige a la página correspondiente en función del tipo de socio, pero ese método ya no forma parte de la identificación en sí

Es mucho rollo, no se si podrás sacar algo de provecho

Comment: Independientemente si me funciona o no solo quiero decir que estás loco  (en buena forma) ya que tú logica para hacer ese trabajo esta muy bien pensada